# Select latest ID only, if it matches criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.5

I have a MySQL table `people` like this:

| id | person_id | meeting_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 21 | 123456 |
| 2 | 21 | 123457 |
| 3 | 21 | 123456 |
| 4 | 22 | 123470 |
| 5 | 21 | 0 |
| 6 | 21 | 123472 |

I need to get 1 row for each `person_id`, but only, if `meeting_time` is between 123451 and 123460. If it is not I don't need the row.

Also I don't need a lower id with higher meeting_time (like id 2) nor I need id 5. However currently I'm getting id 2, instead of id 3.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT MAX(`id`) AS `id`, `person_id`, `meeting_time` 
FROM `people` 
WHERE `meeting_time` > 123451 AND `meeting_time` < 123460 
ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

Edit: The answer given by SelVazi works, so far, however: Since there is `id 6` (I expanded the table with this entry), which has `meeting_time` greater than the max range I should not get any entries, but I'm getting `id 3` (which was correct before I remembered I need that too).

Edit 2: MySQL server 5.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `inner join` :

This is to look for the max `id` grouped by `person_id` then check if `meeting_time` is `between 123451 and 123460`

```
 with cte as ( 
  select p.*
  from people p
  inner join (
    SELECT person_id, max(id) as id
    FROM people
    where meeting_time between 123451 and 123460
    group by person_id
  ) as s on s.id = p.id
)
select c.*
from cte c
inner join (
  SELECT person_id, MAX(meeting_time) as max_meeting_time
  FROM people
  group by person_id
) as s on s.person_id = c.person_id and s.max_meeting_time between 123451 and 123460
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/3DqtgbWf)

---

This is a working query for mysql 5.5

```
select c.*
from ( 
  select p.*
  from people p
  inner join (
    SELECT person_id, max(id) as id
    FROM people
    where meeting_time between 123451 and 123460
    group by person_id
  ) as s on s.id = p.id
) as c
inner join (
  SELECT person_id, MAX(meeting_time) as max_meeting_time
  FROM people
  group by person_id
) as s on s.person_id = c.person_id and s.max_meeting_time between 123451 and 123460
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/N-I03NHH)

Comment: According to the input you shared it should give `id 3 person 21 meeting_time 123456` ! right ?

Comment: Seems working fine : https://onecompiler.com/mysql/3yxdhkces

Comment: @SelVazi
I added one more row to the table. Since it's the newest entry and its `meeting_time` is out of the range I should not get any rows (I'm currently getting `id 3`, which was correct giving my question didn't include that last case.

Comment: @Lanexbg still working fine brother: https://onecompiler.com/mysql/3yxdjam2d

Comment: @Anant - Alive to die, yes, but see that's the problem, It should not return any rows as `id 6` is the newest entry for that person and `meeting_time` is out of range (I edited the question to include that).

Comment: @Lanexbg Can you check my update ?

Comment: @SelVazi then it will not work for the previous condition: https://onecompiler.com/mysql/3yxdjxfkg

Comment: @Lanexbg  you said you want record between `BETWEEN 123451 AND 123460`

Comment: I have made an other update, can you check

Comment: @SelVazi it looks like it's working as I need it. I'll run some more tests and will update you. Thanks.

Comment: @SelVazi, hmm, unfortunately we are using MySQL 5.5 and CTE are not working for us.

Comment: @Lanexbg I added a working query for mysql 5.7

Comment: @SelVazi, your 5.5 query works in an online testing environment so I'll accept it. It's not working for us and we will change the table structure, however. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a correlated subquery. It assumes that `id` is unique:

```
select *
from t
where id = (
    select max(id)
    from t as x
    where x.person_id = t.person_id
    and meeting_time between 123451 and 123460
);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple, old-fashioned `LIMIT`.  No need for `MAX`.

```
SELECT `id`, `person_id`, `meeting_time` 
    FROM `people` 
    WHERE `meeting_time` > 123451 AND `meeting_time` < 123460 
    ORDER BY `id` DESC
    LIMIT 1
```

This would help with performance:

```
INDEX(meeting_time)
```

Works in (at least) MySQL 4.0 and later.